# Howto return proper exit Code with AttachConsole from a Windows Forms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exit-code

I 'am trying to exit a Windows Forms Application with returning the proper exitcode to the attached Console. For Testing i created a simple windows form app with this program.cs. I did take a look at other similar questions here at stackoverflow, but couldn't find a solution so far..

if i test the app in a cmdbox with "ExitTest -test" it should return 84 as errorlevel instead of 0. How can i achieve this ?

I use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExitTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        private const int AttachParentProcess = -1;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

        [STAThread]
        static int Main()
        {
            int returncode = 0;
            if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1)
            {
                // Attach Console to Gui
                AttachConsole(AttachParentProcess);
                Console.WriteLine("This is written to the console");

                //Test ExitCode
                returncode = 84;

                // Sent enter to prevent waiting of Console on Close
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                Environment.ExitCode = returncode;
            }
            else
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());

            }
            return returncode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw an exception? Usually an exit code of 0 means the application ran without error. Anything else indicates an error.

Comment: If you run this code from another program via `Process.Start()`, the `ExitCode` is indeed 84. Don't know why `%errorlevel%` doesn't show it.

Comment: If you start the program from a console, you need to wait for the actual windowed application process to exit and properly set the exit code to `%errrorlevel%`. Try using `start /wait ExitTest -test` instead of just `ExitTest -test`.

Comment: yes, with start /wait it seems to work.